# How to use specific CRS when creating geotools objects?

Tags: java, geometry, geotools

I am having trouble creating geotools buffers around objects (lines), all objects seem crooked, I think it happens because the difference in CRSs is very noticable on buffers. I figuered out I probably need to set CRS that my app is using, i want it to be EPSG:4326 but i cant get my head on how i can do it.

---

Reading geotools guide i've seen examples on how to do it knowing the CRS used before via transform but i can only get SRID code and not the CRS. Any help is apreciated

---

In the code shown below I im trying to constuct buffer over a line and get coordinates of the buffer on the different radiuses. It works just fine, but seems realy uneven on the map. I also tried creating geometry factory specifying SRID assuming the int code would be the same as in CRS, there is no difference in displaying coordinates in different factories whatsoever

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
GeometryFactory factory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
LineString lineString = geometryFactory.createLineString(mapCoords(pipeline));
for (double radius : radiuses){
            Coordinate[] coordinates = lineString.buffer(radius).getCoordinates();
            List<Point> points = mapPoints(coordinates);
            radiusesPoints.add(points);
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the code you are using? how are you creating your features? What projection are they in - buffers don't really work with geographic CRS like 4326.

Comment: @IanTurton I added the code I am using to the question, tell me if you need to se more,
Also map methods in the code needed to convert geotools coordinates to localy created class - point (which are pacticaly the same, but with minimized functionality only for 2D)

Comment: we need to see the output of `mapCoords(pipeline)` to see what is actually happening - but this won't work as JTS doesn't make any use of the SRID you add to the factory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a polygon from a line(GPS coordinate) in a defined distance(km) with geotools in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426901/generate-a-polygon-from-a-linegps-coordinate-in-a-defined-distancekm-with-ge)

Comment: @IanTurton the answer in "Generate a polygon..." question seems just what i need, but is there a way to convert a Geometry object to Feature object? since getDefaultGeometryProperty() is available only on feature object

Comment: you can just use your geometry instead

Comment: @IanTurton It seems like the last thing that doesn't let the app work is i cannot get coordinates of needed geometry, i can get coordinates of a centroid of a geometry, but can i somehow get the coordinates of geometry?

Comment: `geomertry.getCoordinates()` returns an array of `Coordinates`

Comment: @IanTurton I am sorry for bombing you with questions, but there is something wierd about the problem. 'geomertry.getCoordinates()' exists when I use Geometry class from com.vividsolutions.jts.geom, but then I cannot 'getCoordinateReferenceSystem()'. When I use 'org.geotools.geometry.' dependency its exactly on the contrary and I cannot use both methods on the one Geometry object.
And they seems to be non castable.
Meybe important thing is I use geotools version 14.0 and the project runs on java 1.7

Comment: JTS knows nothing about CRS so you can't but since you did a transform on the geometry you know what the CRS is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it was said in the comments, since there is no way to getCoordinates and getCoordinateReferenceSystem on the same object I used a workaround, which is basicly using postgresql fucntions to do the same thing, but on db request level. The task was solved a while ago, but if you would like to see a solution tag me in the comments and I'll find the db request for you